# Sorting through list items using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape images off a website from a li html list.
At the moment I'm stuck trying to be able to find the link to each page from the line items. When I call the function to print the images I can only look at the first item in the list or the entire list. Here's how I do this:

```
#prints all items in the list
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})
for c in containers[1]:
    print(c) 

#prints the first item in the list 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "image_list"})
for c in containers[1].li:
    print(c)
```

How do I select individual items in the list? Each list item has a distinct numbered name. Can I use these numbers to select individual items in the list?

In the end I'd like to loop through only some of the numbers.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post sample of your HTML and what element you want to target? That way we can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "image_list"})
for c in containers:
    print(c) 

#prints the first item in the list 
containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "image_list"})
for c in containers:
    print(c)
```

Replace findAll by find_all and just iterate through the output of find_all which is already a list, so no need to add the index.